# How do I get rid of the space on 262274 and centre the bar on 262277

Tags: python, graph, plotly, visualization

With the following graph;
[image]

I want to

1. eliminate the space between the two columns on 262274
2. centre the bar on 262277.

I tried making the `markercolor="Test_Number"` but it created a stacked bargraph. I also tried the following;

```
bargap=0,
bargroupgap=0,
barmode='group',
```

This is my code.

```
o = go.Figure()
color = ["indigo", "green", "turquoise", "blue", "orange"]
for i in range(1, 6):
    o.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df[df["Test_Number"] == i]["id"],
        y=df[df["Test_Number"] == i]["count"],
        marker_color=color[i - 1],
        name="Test Number " + str(i)
    ))

o.update_layout(title=" Id vs Count", xaxis_title=" id", yaxis_title="Count",
                yaxis=dict(
                    tickmode='linear',
                    tick0=1,
                    dtick=1,
                ))
o.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this issue was raised in 2016 but hasn't been solved yet.
check
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/930